# How to plot a square wave in pgfplots without vertical lines

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a square wave in pgfplots but without the vertical lines (i.e. that it looks like a graph of a function). I tried this, but this obviously cannot work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[samples=1000,no markers,domain=-10:10]
        \addplot gnuplot {sgn(sin(x))};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Maybe it is possible to restrict the y domain to the set `{-1,1}` but I don't know how.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve. Could you add a rough sketch of the plot how it should look like? Do you perhaps mean something like `\addplot+ [samples=51,jump mark mid] {sin(deg(x))};`

Comment: Something like this one: https://services.math.duke.edu/education/modules2/materials/engin/revfour/graphic2_3.gif

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to get this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[samples=1000,no markers,domain=-10:10]
    \addplot+[restrict y to domain=1:1,forget plot] gnuplot {sgn(sin(x))};
    \addplot+[restrict y to domain=-1:-1] table {\jobname.pgf-plot.table};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Explanation:

```
\addplot+[restrict y to domain=1:1,forget plot] gnuplot {sgn(sin(x))};
```

The `+` ensures that the `cycle list` (e.g. plot color) is used for the plot. Because of `gnuplot` the program gnuplot is used to calculate the coordinates for the plot. They are saved in a file `\jobname.pgf-plot.table` in the working directory. `forget plot` ensures that this plot will not go to the legend and the number of plots will not be changed. So the plot in the next step

```
\addplot+[restrict y to domain=-1:-1] table {\jobname.pgf-plot.table};
```

will use the same settings from the `cycle list`. If you add `\addlegendentry` this plot goes to the legend. The table calculated by gnuplot in the first step can be reused.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, thanks. Can you explain the trick with forget plot and the table plot?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the constant plots of pgfplots (see Sec. 4.5.3 in the manual):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[jump mark left,no marks,blue,thick] 
         coordinates {(0,1) (1,-1) (2,1) (3,-1) (4,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```